# Django erro com múltiplos banco de dados | Connection not found

Tags: python, django

Atualmente, estou trabalhando em um projeto onde estou tentando incorporar vários bancos de dados. Permita-me dividir o que fiz até agora:

#### Versão do Django:

Iniciei o processo atualizando o Django da versão 4.2.1 para a 5.0.1, mantendo minha versão do Python constante em 3.10.2.

#### Aplicações:

Inicialmente, meu projeto tinha apenas duas aplicações, mas adicionei uma nova, resultando em um total de três. Importante destacar que não há dependências circulares entre elas. Todas as três aplicações foram devidamente adicionadas às "Configurações" do projeto.

#### Configurações:

Além do banco de dados 'default' existente, introduzi um novo chamado 'manager'. Ajustei o caminho do DATABASE_ROUTERS de acordo nos arquivos do projeto.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.router-manager.ManagerRouter', 'routers.router-api.ApiRouter',]
```

#### Arquivo de Roteadores:

Seguindo as diretrizes na Documentação do Django, criei um arquivo de roteador para gerenciar os modelos de cada aplicação. Aqui está a configuração do meu arquivo de roteador:

```
class ManagerRouter:
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the manager applications
and api applications.
"""

route_app_labels = {"distributor_api", "manager_api"}

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read manager_api and distributor_api models go to 
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return "manager"
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    All writes (i.e. any create or update) should be done to the 'db
    for write' which is set as 'db-distrib-manager'.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return "manager"
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    if(obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
       or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels):
        return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure that everything related to our apps goes into the 'db for
    write', otherwise put it in the default place.
    """
    if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
        return db == "manager"
    return None
```

#### Conclusão:

Apesar de implementar com sucesso as etapas fundamentais necessárias para executar o Django com vários bancos de dados, estou encontrando um erro peculiar ao executar o comando /manage.py migrate --database=migrate --settings=myappsettings.dev.

O rastreamento desse erro é o seguinte:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 58, in __getitem__
    return getattr(self._connections, alias)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 105, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"{self!r} object has no attribute {key!r}")
AttributeError: <asgiref.local.Local object at 0x104b3c6a0> object has no attribute 'manager'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/myophiomics/manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/myophiomics/manage.py", line 20, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 100, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 12, in check_database_backends
    conn = connections[alias]
  File "/Users/mcarvalho/Desktop/MyOphio-v_2.2.0PT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 61, in __getitem__
    raise self.exception_class(f"The connection '{alias}' doesn't exist.")
django.utils.connection.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection 'manager' doesn't exist.
```

Na tentativa de entender melhor o problema, executei o comando `python3 manage.py diffsettings --all`. Embora eu não vá fornecer a saída completa aqui, compartilharei a parte relevante relacionada ao banco de dados. Se necessário, posso fornecer a saída completa.

```
    ### DATABASES = {}
### DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
```

Tenho enfrentado isso por dois dias agora e estou tentando determinar se é devido a más configurações, conflitos ou possivelmente um bug no sistema.

Sinta-se à vontade para compartilhar partes específicas nas quais gostaria de mais esclarecimentos ou modificações.

Answer (score -2):

Eu realmente não sei qual foi a razão para isso. No entanto, consegui resolver esse problema adicionando o seguinte comando ao arquivo manage.py:

```
from django.db import connections

for alias in connections:
    print(alias)
```

Não sei por que, mas isso ajudou a forçar o Django a procurar por conexões e, de repente, imprimiu todos os alias. A partir desse momento, ele reconheceu o banco de dados 'manager'. Se alguém souber a causa raiz desse problema, por favor, explique.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).